# How to validate object serialization mechanism?

Tags: java

I'm trying to validate that my custom Java object is serialized/de-serialized properly, and I can use this serialization mechanism with files, streams, etc. This is the test I created. Is it a correct approach?

```
public class SerializableTest {
  @Test public void shouldSerialize() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo(123);

    // serialize it to a string
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new ObjectOutputStream(out).writeObject(foo);
    String written = out.toString();

    // read it back
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(written.getBytes());
    Foo foo2 = (Foo)(new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject());

    // check that two objects are identical
    assertEquals(foo, foo2);
  }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
String written = out.toString();
```

with

```
byte[] written = out.toByteArray();
```

You can't store random binary data as String. String is for text.

Comment: What is the difference, technically, between `String` and `byte[]`? The same data structure, but with a different public interface. I'm just curious... Besides that, your recommendation helped me and now the test works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Vincenzo You may be confusing `byte` with `char` (and string is essentially a `char[]`). To convert array of bytes (8-bit numbers) to string, some encoding have to be used. And if encoding can't process your input (e.g., there's no character for this number), output is unspecified.

Comment: @Vincenzo Try to play with it. Like, `new String(new byte[] {80, 81, 82})` and `new String(new byte[] {1, 2, 3})`.

Comment: It's not the same data structure. String wraps a char[], and chars are 16-bit unsigned Unicode code points where not all 2^15 values are valid. String is not a container for binary data. byte[] is a container for binary data.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to decode binary data to text and then encode back to binary. Always a bad idea.

You should also flush decorator output streams.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, as long as Foo has a proper equals implementation.

I would not pass it through the String transformation as this is evil as the other also remarked already.